# Correctly handle exceptions in Akka async continuations

Tags: akka.net

To integrate `async / task` methods with `akkling` actor system I've written following method

```
    let actorOfTask (t: 'a -> Task<'b>) =
        (fun (ctx: Actor<_>) ->
        let rec loop() =
            actor {
                let! data = ctx.Receive()
                task {
                    try
                        let! t' = data |> t
                        return t'
                    with e ->
                        // TODO : Raise exception in order to supervisor can catch it
                        printf "Exception %O" e
                        return raise e
                }
                |> Async.AwaitTask
                |!> ctx.Sender()
                
            }
        loop())
```

It is based on suggestion how to integrate actors with async workflows (example here https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/blob/0b5b0ffa4cd516407706ed230f81915452cdb183/tests/Akkling.Tests/Actors.fs#L124)

But issue here if async method throw exception it is not handled by parent supervisor

I'm expecting this code should work but it is not

```
        let ss =
            Strategy.OneForOne(fun error ->
                printf "Error %O" error
                Directive.Escalate)

        let system = System.create "sys" <| Configuration.defaultConfig()
        spawnAnonymous system { props (eventsHandler env) with SupervisionStrategy = Some ss }
```

Though if exception happens in regular actor flow (not integrated with async) this supervisor handle it.

Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From Akka.Net documentation

https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html

```
WARNING
To complete the Task with an exception you need send a Failure message to the sender. This is not done automatically when an actor throws an exception while processing a message.

try
{
    var result = operation();
    Sender.Tell(result, Self);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Sender.Tell(new Failure { Exception = e }, Self);
}
```

So actor should be implemented like this

```
    let actorOfTask (sendTo: IActorRef<_>) (t: 'a -> Task<_>) =
        (fun (ctx: Actor<_>) ->
        let rec loop() =
            actor {
                let! data = ctx.Receive()
                task {
                    try
                        let! t' = data |> t
                        return t' :> obj
                    with e ->
                        return Akka.Actor.Failure(Exception = e) :> obj
                }
                |> Async.AwaitTask
                |!> (retype sendTo)
            }
        loop())
```